# How to change the get access location permission value based on time in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, core-location, geofencing

I work in the Geofence feature using the `CoreLocation` library. The `CoreLocation` library has a `CoreLocationManager` class, which has the `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` permission function.

I want to ask a question, can I change the permission based on time automatically after choosing the always allow? I want to avoid the battery drain. E.g. in peak time (10 AM -10 PM) the permission value will be always allowed and otherwise will be only while using the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, this is not possible directly, however you can work around this.

Several functions allow us to stop and start monitoring. However, if the user has allowed `always`, then background monitoring is always allowable. During your down period you can set [`allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates) to `false` to stop unnecessary background monitoring and/or call this function, [`stopUpdatingLocation()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423695-stopupdatinglocation). This will affect monitoring whilst the apps active.

Here are the [Core Location docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager). Having a dig around in here should answer any other general questions.